# Whats my hostname on my local MySQL server?

Tags: java, mysql, ip, local, hostname

I just set up a MySQL server on my PC for testing Java with JDBC.
At the moment "localhost" works perfectly as hostname for my applications, when running them on the same system.

However what would be the hostname for my MySQL server for applications that are running on different computers? Something like "my_ip:port" would work? I was thinking of writing an applet, which I could upload on a web server and try to connect to my database here. Is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Something like "my_ip:port" would work?

If the MySQL instance has bound to your public interface, and if your firewall allows it, yes. If you connect to the 'net via a router that does NAT (for instance, a combined DSL modem and wireless router allowing you to connect multiple computers), you'll have to set up forwarding rules in the router to tell it which of the local machines to forward requests to.

You don't have to use an IP address. Your machine will also probably have a host name of some kind (either one you've assigned or, if you connect through an ISP, more likely one they've assigned). That would work too.

> I was thinking of writing an applet, which I could upload on a web server and try to connect to my database here. Is it possible to achieve that?

With a [*signed* Java applet](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html), yes; otherwise, no. That's because the security sandbox that Java applets run in doesn't let them access servers other than the one they were loaded from (the web server).

A much better approach is to have your client-side code (Java applet, or just DHTML+Ajax stuff) talk to server-side code on the web server, which in turn talks to your DB. That way, the DB is never directly exposed to the outside world, and you don't have to do things like signed applets.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the ip address of the server running mysql as the hostname or its fully qualified domain name.

Comment: With mysql - not always. If network support is turned off in mysql config you can just use local sockets, not host name or FQN

Answer (score 0):

That should work, but you also should consider port-forwarding through your firewall.

Go here to get your IP: http://www.whatsmyip.org/

The port is the port mysql is setup on.